# With angular-ui google maps how do you re-load new map data or center?

Tags: angular-ui, angular-google-maps

I haven't been able to find a tutorials yet with angular google map that shows how to re-load either map data or re-center the map with new data.

My controller:

```
vm.territories = []; //this gets loaded with the polylines
vm.center = {
            latitude: 40.7450,
            longitude: -99.3965
        }
```

Html:

```
<ui-gmap-google-map center="vm.center" zoom="vm.zoomLevel">
            <ui-gmap-polygon ng-repeat="ct in vm.territories" path="ct.territoryData" stroke="ct.mapStroke" visible="vm.polygon.visible"
                             geodesic="vm.polygon.geodesic" fill="ct.mapFill" editable="vm.polygon.editable">
            </ui-gmap-polygon>
        </ui-gmap-google-map>
```

So question is, if I change the vm.center values or want to add/remove/change vm.territories after the map has already loaded with that data, how do I re-load it after the fact? I was hoping I could bind the data to the ui and change it on the fly but not sure that's possible.

Comment: do you have a jsfiddle or plunkr?

Comment: I guess you could use this base example from angular-google-maps, as it does essentially the same thing.. http://plnkr.co/edit/s5IrKz3v1IejH5PDpsPv?p=preview  The question is how to update the map if you change the center or longitude data after it's already loaded (based on some user input for example). I'm not sure which event to fire.

Comment: ok, I made a small change to your provided plunkr. http://plnkr.co/edit/Aa5yrLw9tEB3JbwsUmhp?p=preview you'll see at the top two input fields, which represents the center of the map. change it and you'll see what happens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as you can see in this [example](http://plnkr.co/edit/Aa5yrLw9tEB3JbwsUmhp?p=preview), you can simply bind your center values to input fields, or use it in other controller functions.

if you add a function to your controller like this:

```
$scope.setCenter = function(lat, lng)
{
    $scope.map.center = {latitude: lat, longitude: lng };
}
```

and call this function from a button like:

```
<button ng-click="setCenter(20, 30)">Set Center</button>
```

you'll notice how the map is centered at the new values.

if you extend the example a little bit more, you'll see, that the same applies for the polygon.

```
$scope.addPoint = function(lat, lng){
   $scope.polygons[0].path.push({latitude: lat, longitude: lng});
}
```

and the button:

```
<button ng-click="addPoint(20, 30)">AddPoint</button>
```

Comment: Seems as thought I was over complicating it! Didn't realize the map was watching those. Thank you.